# Exception occur when fast click

Tags: wpf, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I run WPF in VB.NET. My page is consist of 6 category. Each category will be navigate to its own page. Let's say first page is fashion,followed by eateries,services,health,specialty and interior. When I click like normal person, it not having problem. But when I fast click, like speeding click to eateries then services,then health for some time, it will goes exception at code right at function to navigate. Why is this happen on fast click? Steady click not having problem.

Exception goes at navigate with the title "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled":

```
Private Sub navigate()
    Select Case mytab
        Case 1
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory1Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        Case 2
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory2Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        Case 3
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory3Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        Case 4
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory4Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        Case 5
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory5Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        Case 6
            NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(GotoCategory6Screen, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    End Select
End Sub
```

Any ways to handle this?

Comment: You have to figure out exactly what line the problem occurs. That should be in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Usually fast click is not an issue but you have another method which does not use a uri hence do not require initialization from a uri

You can use other over load of `NavigationService.Navigate` which uses instance instead of uri, so you can guarantee the initialization has been done before navigation. this will also enable you to detect the error source, initialization or navigation.

eg

```
 Category1Screen screen1 = new Category1Screen();
 NavigationService.Navigate(screen1);
```

above class `Category1Screen` is just a sample, you have to use actual classes.

that should solve the issue, if issue still persist then probably you are missing the concerned code, you may have to look within the initialization code of your screens

Comment: i will try it..seems legit.